# Git Extensions conflict with msysgit 1.9.5

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-extensions

As I'm pretty new to git, I need help in the problem I'm having.

On one of our servers we have git installed (1.9.5.msysgit.0). GUI used is TortoiseGit.

I installed Git Extensions 2.49 to use it instead of Tortoise. I opened the existing repo without any problems in Git Extensions. But when I try to switch branches, or pull, it hangs and CPU spikes to 100%. There are 3-4 git.exe processes opened at that time eating up the whole CPU.

My question is:

Is it a Git Extensions 2.49 conflict with current git version, or some other issue? Did anyone have something like that?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Dmitry

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in Git Extensions which caused long 100% CPU load if you have lots of branches. I'm not sure whether this bug is fixed in recent version.

Apart from this you should consider updating Git for Windows, the current version is 2.12.